# CentOS 7 Default Groups that are safe to remove

Tags: centos7, groups

**Problem**

I would like to know the purpose of each group and what type of issues would occur if the group is deleted. CentOS 7 comes the following default groups (courtesy of @HBruijn)

```
# rpm -qf /etc/group
setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch
# yum install yum-utils 
# yum download setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch 
# rpm2cpio setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch.rpm  | cpio -idmv
...
./etc/group:

root:x:0:
bin:x:1:
daemon:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:
cdrom:x:11:
mail:x:12:
man:x:15:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
games:x:20:
tape:x:30:
video:x:39:
ftp:x:50:
lock:x:54:
audio:x:63:
nobody:x:99:
users:x:100:
```

**Desired Resolution**

Official documentation stating that deleting default groups can cause issues and should be avoided, or official documentation stating the purpose for each group and its purpose.

Thanks in advanced for everyone's help!

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? This will only cause issues when upgrading or migrating.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I do not want to remove them. I am actually asking the question specifically because I fear that by removing the groups, I will cause issues when upgrading, or migrating. I am looking for empirical evidence that I can present as to why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html) lists only 3 mandatory groups: `root`, `daemon` and `bin` and some common optional ones.

For RHEL and CentOS 7 it is the  `setup` package that installs a number of defaults, including the barebones `/etc/group` with a number of groups:

```
# rpm -qf /etc/group
setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch
# yum install yum-utils 
# yum download setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch 
# rpm2cpio setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch.rpm  | cpio -idmv
...
./etc/group:

root:x:0:
bin:x:1:
daemon:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:
cdrom:x:11:
mail:x:12:
man:x:15:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
games:x:20:
tape:x:30:
video:x:39:
ftp:x:50:
lock:x:54:
audio:x:63:
nobody:x:99:
users:x:100:
```

which seems a fairly limited set. I assume all of those are needed by the base OS.

Typically additional groups will be installed as needed by specific packages that you install on top of the base system.

I *think* that groups created by installing packages are frequently not removed if and when removing the package, as not to leave data with numeric only GID's.